# Determine IP Address of a thin client running WinCE 3.0

Tags: compact-framework

Is there a setting in CF that show this info? Something like Machine.IPAddress?

Thanks!

I am using Asp.net CF .net 2.0 and c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got it:

```
 using System.Net;

    string strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
    IPHostEntry hostInfo = Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName);
    string strIPAddress = hostInfo.AddressList[0].ToString();
```

Comment: `Dns.GetHostByName` is deprecated. Any new solutions using this code should use `Dns.GetHostEntry` instead. The function signatures are the same, so it's a drop-in replacement.